# Step by Step validating jquery-steps form with bootstrap validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-steps, bootstrapvalidator

I have a multistep form made using jquery-steps (https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps). I am using bootstrap validator plugin (https://github.com/formvalidation/formvalidation.io) I am able to get the validation rules working on field while typing (it shows the validation on the fly while user is typing).

But If a required field is left blank, or the user did not provide a valid information in a field and clicks on the next, the step moves ahead. I want to prevent the user from moving on to next step, if any field is showing "Invalid" or a "Required" field is not filled. How to accomplish this?

Comment: Help us and post the code so we Help you.

Comment: It's a long code, I don't know it will fit here. Still trying...
NO ! It don't fit here... How can post code? its 306 lines...

Comment: create a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ or pastebin http://pastebin.com/

Comment: Here is my pastebin : http://pastebin.com/85iMt3QG

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using validation plugin and jQuery-step plugin separate and they handling there functions independently, that's the reason even if input is invalid, on next button click, it skips the validation error and move to next step.

```
$("#wizard").steps({
    headerTag: "h2",
    bodyTag: "section",
    saveState: true,
})

$('#multiphase').bootstrapValidator({
    //Validation rules and messages
})
```

- You are using [bootstrapvalidator](http://bv.doc.javake.cn/) plugin which has no API support, callback function support for `jQuery-Step Plugin` and even it's development discontinued
- [jQuery-Step Plugin](http://www.jquery-steps.com/) has it's own validation mechanishm and I haven't found any reference and support for [bootstrapvalidator](http://bv.doc.javake.cn/) in there examples and documents.

So suggest don't waste time with the code and try to make it work (which needs loads of customization) instead use [bootstrapFormValidation](http://formvalidation.io/examples/jquery-steps/) plugin which basically the upgrade of [bootstrapvalidator](http://bv.doc.javake.cn/) plugin and has fully [working example with jQuery-Step Plugin](http://formvalidation.io/examples/jquery-steps/) and have better support

So without major changes in your HTML code, you can just replace the [bootstrapvalidator](http://bv.doc.javake.cn/) plugin with [bootstrapFormValidation](http://formvalidation.io/examples/jquery-steps/) plugin and can achieve the desired result with smiling face. :)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    function adjustIframeHeight() {
        var $body   = $('body'),
            $iframe = $body.data('iframe.fv');
        if ($iframe) {
            // Adjust the height of iframe
            $iframe.height($body.height());
        }
    }
    $("#multiphase").steps({
        headerTag: "h2",
        bodyTag: "section",
        saveState: true,
  onStepChanged: function(e, currentIndex, priorIndex) {
                // You don't need to care about it
                // It is for the specific demo
                adjustIframeHeight();
            },
            // Triggered when clicking the Previous/Next buttons
            onStepChanging: function(e, currentIndex, newIndex) {
                var fv         = $('#multiphase').data('formValidation'), // FormValidation instance
                    // The current step container
                    $container = $('#multiphase').find('section[data-step="' + currentIndex +'"]');

                // Validate the container
                fv.validateContainer($container);

                var isValidStep = fv.isValidContainer($container);
                if (isValidStep === false || isValidStep === null) {
                    // Do not jump to the next step
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            },
            // Triggered when clicking the Finish button
            onFinishing: function(e, currentIndex) {
                var fv         = $('#multiphase').data('formValidation'),
                    $container = $('#multiphase').find('section[data-step="' + currentIndex +'"]');

                // Validate the last step container
                fv.validateContainer($container);

                var isValidStep = fv.isValidContainer($container);
                if (isValidStep === false || isValidStep === null) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            },
            onFinished: function(e, currentIndex) {
                // Uncomment the following line to submit the form using the defaultSubmit() method
                //$('#multiphase').formValidation('defaultSubmit');

                // For testing purpose
                $('#welcomeModal').modal("show");
            }
        }).formValidation({
        excluded: ':disabled',
        message: 'This value is not valid',
        container: 'tooltip',
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            //last name validation  
            sd_lastname: {
                container: 'popover',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Last Name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            //first name validation
            sd_firstname: {
                container: 'popover',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The First Name is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The First Name must be more than 7 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[A-Z]+$/i,
                        message: 'The First Name can only consist of alphabetical characters'
                    }
                }
            },
            //validation of Parent's details step start
            //last name validation  
            pd_lastname: {
                container: 'popover',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Last Name is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            //first name validation
            pd_firstname: {
                container: 'popover',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The First Name is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 3,
                        max: 30,
                        message: 'The First Name must be more than 7 and less than 30 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[A-Z]+$/i,
                        message: 'The First Name can only consist of alphabetical characters'
                    }
                }
            },
            // Validation for Reference details starts
            //School reference name
            rd_schoolrefname: {
                container: 'popover',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The School Reference Name is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    stringLength: {
                        min: 7,
                        max: 40,
                        message: 'The School Reference Name must be more than 7 and less than 40 characters long'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /^[A-Z\s]+$/i,
                        message: 'The School Reference Name can only consist of alphabetical characters'
                    }
                }
            },
            //School reference phone
            rd_schoolrefmobile: {
                container: 'popover',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The Phone or Mobile is required and cannot be empty'
                    }
                }
            },
            rd_schoolrefemail: {
                container: 'popover',
                validators: {
                    notEmpty: {
                        message: 'The E-Mail ID is required and cannot be empty'
                    },
                    regexp: {
                        regexp: /[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:(\.|_)[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^`{|}~-]+)*@(?!([a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]*\.))(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]*[a-zA-Z0-9])?/g,
                        message: 'The E-Mail ID is not a valid E-Mail'
                    }
                }
            },
        }

    })

});
```

```css
.wizard > .content {
min-height: 20em !important;
}
.wizard .content > .body {
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 15px;
position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formvalidation/0.6.1/css/formValidation.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/jquery.steps/css/jquery.steps.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formvalidation/0.6.1/js/formValidation.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/formvalidation/0.6.1/js/framework/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://formvalidation.io/vendor/jquery.steps/js/jquery.steps.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
<!-- main container div-->
<div id="container" class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div id="maincontent" class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
   <div class="row">
    <div id="" class="col-lg-12">
     <form id="multiphase" role="form" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="post">
        <h2>Step</h2>
       <section data-step="0">
         <h2>Student's Details:</h2>

        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="sd_lastname" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Last Name:</label>
         <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" name="sd_lastname" id="sd_lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" value="" tabindex="1">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="sd_firstname" class="col-lg-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
         <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" name="sd_firstname" id="sd_firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" value="" tabindex="2">
         </div>
        </div>
       </section>
        <h2>Step</h2>

       <section data-step="1">
         <h2>Parent's Details:</h2>

        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="pd_lastname" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Last Name:</label>
         <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" name="pd_lastname" id="pd_lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" value="" tabindex="1">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="pd_firstname" class="col-lg-2 control-label">First Name:</label>
         <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" name="pd_firstname" id="pd_firstname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" value="" tabindex="2">
         </div>
        </div>
       </section>
        <h2>Step</h2>

       <section data-step="2">
         <h2>Reference Details:</h2>

        <hr>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="rd_schoolrefname" class="col-lg-3 control-label">School Principal's Name:</label>
         <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" name="rd_schoolrefname" id="rd_schoolrefname" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name Last Name" value="" tabindex="1">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="rd_schoolrefmobile" class="col-lg-3 control-label">Phone or Mobile No.:</label>
         <div class="col-lg-2">
          <input type="text" name="rd_schoolrefmobile" id="rd_schoolrefmobile" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone or Mobile Number" data-mask="+99-99999-99999" value="" tabindex="2">
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
         <label for="rd_schoolrefemail" class="col-lg-3 control-label">E-Mail ID:</label>
         <div class="col-lg-3">
          <input type="text" name="rd_schoolrefemail" id="rd_schoolrefemail" class="form-control" placeholder="E-Mail ID" value="" tabindex="3">
         </div>
        </div>
       </section>
      <!-- end of wizard-->
     </form>
     <!-- end of form-->
    </div>
   </div>
   <!-- end of row-->
   <div class="modal fade" id="welcomeModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h1 class="modal-title text-center">Add new last name</h1>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       <form method="POST" name="add_lastname">
        <input type="text" name="add_lastname" id="add_lastname" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your last name here" value="">
        <p class="">The first alphabet of the last name <strong>MUST</strong> be in upper case.</p>
       </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
       <input name="addlastname" type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="row hidden-print">
  <div id="footer" class="col-lg-12"></div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/1cdjy45s/1/)

Comment: This is nice... working as expacted. One thing I noticed :
When I tested your code copying it directly to my file (with includes from cdn's), it works very well. But when I replace the cdn's with my local downloaded files (css and js) the same code behave differently. Each field on the step is validated one at a time on clicking next. I mean if there are 6 fields on step 1, i will have to click next 6 times to move on the next step. 

This is not the case when using the includes direct from the "cdn's and http" source. Strange!

@Shehary, do you have any idea?

Comment: Yes! that's what I mean

Comment: I solved the problem. There are 2 bootstrap.min.js files and both are required. Another problem!!! The datepicker is being validated. I tried keeping it blank and on clicking next, it turned red. That's OK, but now even if I put the date in it, it won't turn green. I even tried the instructions given here (http://formvalidation.io/examples/bootstrap-datepicker/) but of no use.

Comment: I'm on mobile so cant answer it  check answer on my profile its title is bootstrap form validation validates all the fields inside same form group, you will find the reason n solution

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32942717/bootstrap-form-validation-validates-all-the-fields-inside-same-form-group/32943471#32943471

Comment: Here is my code : http://pastebin.com/mMSJSDQ3

First try and click next without filling anything. Then on error fill in the details. The date field will not validate even a date is selected.

Comment: remove `date` from `<div class="input-group date">` here is working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1cdjy45s/3/ lemme know if it fixed the issue

Comment: your jsfiddle is also behaving the same way. Please check. What I am saying is if by accident or intentionally I click next button without filling any data, it is showing validation errors. This part is ok. But now after pressing next (without filling data and selecting date) and in the fields which are showing "invalid" status, I fill data, the 2 text fields validate but the date does not even if I select the date.

Comment: now i get you, the date work fine if filled before button click but if missed and next button clicked after that even date filled still gives error of invalid input

Comment: Yes! I got it. Working fine now.

Comment: see the end of the JS code, datepicker, added change event of date input with the validation plugin

Comment: Got to appritiate you buddy ... great help